# build successful but no exe file - Install Magick on Visual studio 2010 - MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, imagemagick

I want to use ImageMagick in a MFC program. I have downloaded the ImageMagick and followed the instruction to install it on my system. However I encountered a problem at the first step. I opened and converted the configure.sln under visual studio 2010. I received an error when I pressed the play button to run the program; stating that “unable to start the program configure.exe… the system cannot find the specific file.” I do appreciate if you provide me the instructions to install it under visual 2010.

I went to VisualMagick\configure folder and opened the configure.sln. I also sat the build configuration to Release. However I am still receiving the same error.

I do appreciate if someone suggest me what to do ?

Many Thanks,
Shervin Zargham

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: configure, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/5/2013 11:18:19 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1> Deleting file ".\Release\configure\configure.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1> Creating ".\Release\configure\configure.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" 
was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1> stdafx.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> WaitDlg.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> configure.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> configure_wizard.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> finished_page.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> system_page.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> target_page.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> welcome_page.cpp
1> _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1> Generating Code...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): 
warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\Shervin_Zargham\Industrial Projects\LED   
Display\ImageMagick-6.8.5-4\ImageMagick-6.8.5\VisualMagick\configure\.\Release
\configure\configure.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 
(D:\Shervin_Zargham\Industrial Projects\LED Display\ImageMagick-6.8.5-4\ImageMagick
6.8.5\VisualMagick\configure\configure.exe). This may cause your project to build   
incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and
$(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>Link:
1> configure.vcxproj -> D:\Shervin_Zargham\Industrial Projects\LED Display\ImageMagick-
6.8.5-4\ImageMagick-6.8.5\VisualMagick\configure\.\Release\configure\configure.exe
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1> Deleting file ".\Release\configure\configure.unsuccessfulbuild".
1> Touching ".\Release\configure\configure.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:22.43
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and
$(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).` Might wanna check your project settings

Comment: @mwerschy: thank you so much for your comment. but I do not understand the message. can you inform me what to do ?

Comment: In the project properties check `General\Output Directory, Name, Extension` and `Linker\General\Output File`. The linker out directory should probably be `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`